# Age filter for gridview not working properly

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that displays some data from a table within my database, convertys dob to age, and I have a dropdownlist that acts as a filter so I can select children within an age group. The first age group 6-10 works fine but 11-13 shows under 11's as well. And 14-16 does the same (essentially showing everyone). I've included my .cs code as well as my source code, along with screenshots of how the webpage looks, could someone point out what I need to change in my code so that the ages are filtered correctly? Thanks.

[image]

.CS CODE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Coursework
{
public partial class Testy1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //create a datasource
    SqlDataSource source = new SqlDataSource();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //always set some defaults for the sqldatasource
        source.ID = "source1";
        source.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newregDBConnectionString"].ConnectionStr‌​ing;
        source.SelectCommand = "SELECT firstname, dob, DATEDIFF(hour, dob, GETDATE()) / 8766 AS age FROM children ORDER BY age";

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //bind the grid
            GridView1.DataSource = source;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //the new database query, now with where clause
        source.SelectCommand = "SELECT firstname, dob, DATEDIFF(hour, dob, GETDATE()) / 8766 AS age FROM children WHERE (DATEDIFF(hour, dob, GETDATE()) / 8766 BETWEEN @start AND @end) ORDER BY age";

        //get the end age from the dropdown and cast as int
        int end = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

        //get the start int for the filter
        int start = end - 11;

        //if the filter is resetted, make sure the query returns all ages
        if (end == 6)
        {
            start = 6;
            end = 99;
        }

        //replace the parameters in the query
        source.SelectParameters.Add("start", start.ToString());
        source.SelectParameters.Add("end", end.ToString());

        //rebind the grid
        GridView1.DataSource = source;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

}

SOURCE CODE:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Testy1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Coursework.Testy1" %>
```

```
<asp:ListItem Text="6 - 10" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="11 - 13" Value="13"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="14 - 16" Value="16"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("firstname") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOB">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("dob")).ToString("d MMMM yyyy") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Age">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("age") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where you need to examine your code:

```
    //get the end age from the dropdown and cast as int
    int end = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

    //get the start int for the filter
    int start = end - 11;

    //if the filter is reset, make sure the query returns all ages
    if (end == 6)
    {
        start = 6;
        end = 99;
    }
```

More specifically the following line: `int start = end - 11;`

It should be clear what you need to change.

Comment: I knew that was the area and I have messed with the values but i'm not seeing the exact figure that it should be changed to, even though I know it is right in front of me. No matter what I change the -11 to, it still won't display the ages correctly in the groups!

Comment: I changed it to - 2; and it works, except that when I add a 6 year old, they don't show up when I filter 6-10. Is this because my age groups are different sizes, 6-10 = 4, 11-13 & 14-16 = 2?

Comment: Yes.  You will either need to change your age range or find another way to set those values.

Comment: Ah, as I thought. They are the age ranges specified by my professor. I'll see if I can change them. Thank you :)

Comment: I doubt your professor will let you change the ranges as he probably wants you to use a `switch` block.  If you are working on things for a class, you should mention that you are asking a [homework](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) question so that people can understand that you are trying to learn; it will change the quality of the answers you get and probably be more helpful to you in the long term.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Kateract I will be sure to mention that in future! Thanks!